# Was it an intentional to cast Nick Frost as Santa just because of his name?

Tags: doctor-who

My only basis for assuming this is that one of the names Santa can go by is Saint Nicholas and in Slovenia he also goes by the name Dedek Mraz (Grandfather Frost).

So i'm looking for an official statement indicating if was on purpose to cast Nick Frost as Santa in *Death in Heaven* and the following Christmas Episode because of his name or just a coincidence and their names somewhat match up.

Comment: Casting? Nick Frost **is** Santa.

Comment: I think you're asking whether he was cast in that role because of his name. You might update your question to make that clearer.

Comment: I really do not understand the downvotes, and hope the downvoters reconsider.

Comment: I didn't vote either way, but it's kind of a ridiculous idea that anyone would be cast in anything solely because of their name. If I were a betting man, I'd guess that that's the reason for downvotes.

Comment: @phantom42, I'm certain it didn't hurt his chances at the part, though. If I were the person in charge of hiring an actor for the role of Santa after the auditions were over and there were two strong candidates, one of which was named "Nick Frost", I know which I would choose to hire.

Comment: There's a strong overlap between the cast of the comedy show "Spaced" and Doctor Who.  Jessica Hynes, Simon Pegg, Bill Bailey, Michael Smiley, Mark Gattis, John Simm all appeared in Spaced.  It's clearly Nick Frost's turn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Consider it a happy coincidence. [Nick Frost](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0296545/) is an actor who enjoys the Doctor Who franchise and happens to be available for the next Christmas episode.

#### [From the Mary Sue:](http://www.themarysue.com/doctor-who-christmas-special-teaser/)

> - Considering Nick Frost’s actual real-life-name is Nick Frost, this is some pretty delightful casting. Here’s the BBC’s description of the episode:
> - "It’s Christmas in the North Pole when the Doctor and Clara return to BBC AMERICA in an all-new Christmas special. Last year’s special featured the emotional regeneration that marked the start of Peter Capaldi’s run as the Twelfth Doctor.
> - This year the Time Lord and his companion are in for an all-new adventure as stars Capaldi and Jenna Coleman are joined by Nick Frost (the actor and screenwriter of Spaced and Shaun of the Dead) as Santa Claus!"

#### From [Variety Magazine's interview](http://variety.com/2014/tv/news/doctor-who-christmas-special-nick-frost-guest-star-1201309899/) with Nick Frost:

> “I’m so thrilled to have been asked to guest in the ‘Doctor Who’ Christmas special, I’m such a fan of the show,” Frost said in a statement. “The read-through was very difficult for me; I wanted to keep stuffing my fingers into my ears and scream ‘No spoilers!’ Every day on set I’ve had to silence my internal fan boy squeals!”